# Replacing an element in a std::vector without operator=

Tags: c++, stdvector

If I emplace an element into a `std::vector` by using `emplace` or `emplace_back`, the element will be constructed without needing an `operator=`.

Now I already have a `std::vector` with elements, and I want to set an element at an index to a new value. This is my current solution, a new solution should behave the same:

```cpp
std::vector<Type> vec;
// ... fill the vector
for (int value = 0; value <= 10; ++value)
  vec.emplace_back( Type(value) );
// replace at index
int index = 5;
Type newelement {30};
vec.erase( vec.begin() + i );
vec.insert( vec.begin() + i, newelement );
```

But I obviously don't want to do just that, as that moves all the other elements in the `std::vector` around, which makes an O(1) complexity task take O(n) time.

Edit:
I changed the code snipped to use `insert`, which is how it actually is in my current code. I now realize that I am confused by not knowing the difference between `insert` and `emplace`. Maybe clarifying that would answer this question, too.

Comment: Why are you trying do do this in this way? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So you want to replace an opject by another without using ```operator=```?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking: "I have a vector of `T`s. I want to assign a new value to one of the elements of the vector, but `T` is designed to not be assignable (has no `operator=`)." Is that a fair summary?

Comment: Does `Type` support move semantics?

Comment: A rather heretic way is to use the *in place* `new` to construct an element at a known address. Simply do not forget to *destroy* the element that lived there...

Comment: Yes, the Goal is to avoid the `operator=`. In my case it is because the old implementation used the code snipped I posted but obviously was a huge bottleneck.
I don't want my new code to behave differently

Comment: It should behave correctly, no matter what the `Type` actually is.
If my code snippet uses `move`, then a potential answer should use it, too.

Comment: @DanielBauer: Your (slow) workaround in the question also uses `operator=` many times, it merely is buried inside the `vec.erase()` and `vec.insert()` calls.

Comment: If the only requirement is to not directly use `operator=` and indirect usage is allowed, then `std::swap()` is the ticket.

Comment: @BenVoigt can you show which constructors/operators are used if I either go with the `erase`/`insert` code or if I just use the `=` directly?

Comment: `erase` and `insert` use move assignment `Type::operator=(Type&&)` to shuffle all later elements back and forth (unless `Type` has a nothrow copy assignment and a throwing move assignment, then these functions will use copy assignment `Type::operator=(const Type&)`)

Comment: if there is no assignment operator (or move assignment) then `vec.erase` would not compile (vector assigns items to move them around). So apparently question has missing some details.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use `vec[index] = Type(30);` which uses move assignment because the new element is temporary. You need move assignment anyway for `std::erase`.

If for some reason you want to name the temporary element, you could instead use `vec[index] = std::move(newelement);`.

Comment: This is definitely what OP should be doing, however he's imposed a nonsensical requirement of avoiding `operator=` (while giving example code that calls it)

Comment: Yeah, it only makess sense if we are talking about copy assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```cpp
vec.erase( vec.begin() + i );
vec.insert( vec.begin() + i, newelement );
```

can be replaced with

```cpp
std::swap( vec.at( i ), newelement );
```

This method will not shift the contents of the vector.

Please feel free to edit this answer to show if and how this method differs apart from not shifting the vector contents.

Comment: It will work, that's why I suggested it.  The default implementation of `std::swap` is still going to use `operator=` inside.

Comment: This Is what I came up with, but am not sure if this will behave exactly the same (obviously not in runtime, but in (side) effects)

Comment: The difference is that the previous vector entry isn't destroyed immediately, it is placed in `newelement`.  It will be destroyed as soon as `newelement` goes out of scope.

Comment: and apart from that it behaves completely indistinguishable after the scope ends?

Comment: Yes, but it still isn't clear to me why you are avoiding `vec[i] = std::move(newelement);` which is happening inside of `std::swap()` anyway.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, your example is not correct since you should pass just the arguments of `Type`'s constructor to `emplace_back`, not a full object. Your loop would look like this

```
std::vector<Type> vec;
for (int value = 0; value <= 10; ++value)
  vec.emplace_back(value);
```

Then, according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace), when using `emplace` there is no need to call `erase` first if an element already exists at the requested position.

> The element is constructed through std::allocator_traits::construct,
> which typically uses placement-new to construct the element in-place
> at a location provided by the container. However, if the required
> location has been occupied by an existing element, the inserted
> element is constructed at another location at first, and then move
> assigned into the required location.

Something like this

```
// replace at index
int index = 5;
vec.emplace( vec.begin() + index, 30);
```

constructs an object at the desired position with a better complexity than calling `erase` first.

Comment: Does this mean that https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace/ is wrong? It says, that emplace will increase the vectors size by one.

Comment: @DanielBauer no not really

Comment: "This effectively increases the container size by one." seems to contradict this answer

Comment: `vec.emplace( vec.begin() + index, 30)` does insert a new element into the vector (before `vec.begin() + index`) its complexity is linear in distance between instert position and end of the container, because thats the number of elements that must be shifted by one position. Your solution has same complexity as calling `erase` first (maybe there is a factor of 2 but that doesnt affect complexity)

Comment: You quoted the section describing why this does not meet OP's requirements, particularly that `emplace` causes move assignment.  Move assignment is `operator=`.